# What does わけもない mean?

Tags: grammar

> Xの声無き叫びが、Yたちに届くわけもない。

EDIT : I think that it is another way of saying "わけがない" but then what is the difference with "わけもない".

Comment: What is 「無き叫び」?  Should it be「泣き叫び」?

Comment: I just make sure that it was correct and it is indeed "声無き叫び". It should mean "voiceless scream".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> 1. 叫び声が　届くわけがない
> 2. 叫び声が　届くわけもない

1. There is no reason that the cry could arrive.
2. There is no reason that the cry even could arrive.

The latter sentence is the stressed form of the former one by 「も」in place of 「が」.

Comment: 1番の訳は" **There** is..."で、2番の訳は" **This**  is..."になっていますが、書き間違いではないのですよね・・・？